# fetch partial string in with start and end

Tags: python, string, function, dataframe, substring

I'm trying to extract dates from strings with a start and end string.

example:

```
comment = " text text text due on: 12/31/2015. REVIEWER'S COMMENTS:     APPROVED. text text text"
start = "due on:"
end = "."
```

I want everything between `due on:` and the first period after that to be returned, which is `12/31/2015`

Instead my code returns:

```
>>> print(comment1.partition(start)[-1].rpartition(end)[0])

12/31/2015. REVIEWER'S COMMENTS:     APPROVED
```

It seems like my code is returning everything between start and the period after "Approved" but I want it to end at the period after the date.

Comment: You don't want rpartition: `comment1.partition(start)[-1].partition(end)[0]`

Comment: You could also use reg exp like `re.findall('due on:(.*)\.', comment)`. It seems much more easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> [`rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition): Split the string at the last occurrence of sep

Since your `end="."` occurs last after `APPROVED.`, this position is used for the split.

You want the first occurence after `due on:`, so another [`partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) on the remainder of your first split:

```
>>> comment.partition(start)[-1].partition(end)[0].strip()
'12/31/2015'
```